# Static able view cell font size is not changing

Tags: ios, uitableview, static, cell, uifont

I'm just loading a TableView with static cells inside a container view.
The cell style is basic. I'm trying to change font size.

In the storyboard all is appearing right. But when running the app in the simulator, I noticed that the font is not the same I set in the storyboard.

Notice: I didn't create a class for the table view controller because it has a static content.

I'm developing on xCode 7.3 and for iOS 9 and later.

Any hints will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
Cell.TextLabel.Font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:36]
```

You have change in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: I don't want to create a hole class fore only changing label font. I already know this will work!